# Getting error `repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied` in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, asp.net-core

While deploying dotnet app as docker with Milticontainer option in Elasticbean stalk, Getting the error like

```
2021-05-20 01:26:55    ERROR   ECS task stopped due to: Task failed to start. (traveltouchapi: CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for traveltouchapi, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
postgres_image: )
2021-05-20 01:26:58    ERROR   Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.
2021-05-20 01:27:00    ERROR   [Instance: i-0844a50e307bd8b23] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: .
```

Environment details for: TravelTouchApi-dev3
Application name: TravelTouchApi
Region: ap-south-1
Deployed Version: app-c1ba-210520_065320
Environment ID: e-i9t6f6vszk
Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:ap-south-1::platform/Multi-container Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.26.0
Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
CNAME: TravelTouchApi-dev3.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
Updated: 2021-05-20 01:23:27.384000+00:00

My Dockerfile is

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build

# Install Node.js
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y \
        nodejs \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /src/TravelTouchApi
COPY ["TravelTouchApi.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "TravelTouchApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TravelTouchApi"
RUN dotnet build "TravelTouchApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build


FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TravelTouchApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish


FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TravelTouchApi.dll"]
```

My docker-compose.yml is

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
    traveltouchapi-dev:
        driver: bridge

services:
    traveltouchapi:
        image: traveltouchapi:latest
        depends_on:
            - "postgres_image"
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        environment:
            DB_CONNECTION_STRING: "host=postgres_image;port=5432;database=blogdb;username=bloguser;password=bloguser"
        networks:
            - traveltouchapi-dev

    postgres_image:
        image: postgres:latest
        ports:
            - "5432"
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - db_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: "bloguser"
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "bloguser"
            POSTGRES_DB: "blogdb"
        networks:
            - traveltouchapi-dev
volumes:
    db_volume:
```

My Dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "POSTGRES_USER",
          "value": "bloguser"
        },
        {
          "name": "POSTGRES_PASSWORD",
          "value": "bloguser"
        },
        {
          "name": "POSTGRES_DB",
          "value": "blogdb"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "image": "postgres:latest",
      "memory": 200,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "containerPath": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
          "sourceVolume": "Db_Volume"
        }
      ],
      "name": "postgres_image",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 5432
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "DB_CONNECTION_STRING",
          "value": "host=postgres_image;port=5432;database=blogdb;username=bloguser;password=bloguser"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "image": "traveltouchapi:latest",
      "name": "traveltouchapi",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "hostPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "memory": 200
    }
  ],
  "family": "",
  "volumes": [
    {
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "db_volume"
      },
      "name": "Db_Volume"
    }
  ]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the login step before deploy the applications.

Can you try use this command before deploying?

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_DEFAULT_ACCID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
```

The image name must contains with full repo/tag name 'natheesh/traveltouchapi: latest'  in Dockerrun.json

Comment: Can you show me the full error? 
And the step you are doing too

Comment: ` 
ERROR
Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.
\n
ERROR
ECS task stopped due to: Task failed to start. (traveltouchapi: CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for traveltouchapi, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied postgres_image: )
\n
ERROR
Failed to start ECS task: arn:aws:ecs:ap-south-1:802684962806:task/awseb-TravelTouchApi-dev-mqs9xrzen5/82a2da45b960475ea1740569a302c8f6 is STOPPED.`

Comment: You need to check 3 things:
1. Your instances have the policy to pull image from ECR
2. That image and repo is exists or not (repo, tags,...)
3. You can run docker pull manually in that instance or not

Comment: Yes Ask... I got it i tried to pull image without having the repo name.... The image name should be natheesh/traveltouchapi: latest , after fixing this it started working.... Thank you for your help....

Comment: No problem ^^ Have a nice day